# Flutter: Where should I call SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark)

Tags: dart, flutter

In my flutter app, screen A has no AppBar.
So I call `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark)` in build.

After another screen B which has an AppBar was pushed and then popped, 
screen A has light status bar.

I'd like the system UI to return to the original setting when the screen is popped.

[image: Gif]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason behind this is the fact that your new screen will have its own lifecycle and thus, might use another color for the status bar.

You can call `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark)` in your `initState` method but that won't trigger after a stacked screen is popped. There are two problems here, you can, however, call that back again after returning from a screen `pop()`. Simple enough right? Almost there.

When you press the back button on the `AppBar` widget, will return immediately from your `Navigator.of(context).push(someroute)`, even if the navigation animation is still being rendered from the stacked screen.
To handle this, you can add a little "tweak" that will set the status bar color again after 500 milseconds, that should be enough for the animation to fully complete. So, you'll want something more or less like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _updateAppbar();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _updateAppbar() {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Navigate to second screen'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondScreen()))
                .whenComplete(() => Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((_) => _updateAppbar()))));
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Although this works, I'm still curious to know if someone knows a better way to handle this though and keep a status bar color binding to each screen.

Comment: So I need to call `_updateAppbar` everytime a page is pushed?

Comment: This has been answered 2y ago, however, if you are not using a `Scaffold` in each page with an `AppBar` with `brightness` property set (which handles the status bar color for you), I'd say yes.

Comment: ```WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _updateAppbar();
}```

Answer (score 6):

maybe you can wrap the whole page widget with AnnotatedRegion like this:

```
AnnotatedRegion(
value: _currentStyle,
child: Center(
  child: ElevatedButton(
    child: const Text('Change Color'),
    onPressed: _changeColor,
   ),
 ),
);
```

you can follow the full example here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html

Comment: Great, this should be the accepted answear.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that works

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.transparent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this package to your project [Need Resume](https://pub.dev/packages/need_resume) and *extends* your screen state to **ResumableState**

```
import 'package:need_resume/need_resume.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const WelcomeScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends ResumableState<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  void onResume() {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
    super.onResume();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This solutions works as expected with very little changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the main screen:

```
void main() {
 
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: This is a better way to call system chrome compared to above examples

Answer (score 0):

Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300)).then((value) =>
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark));

i found that you can acctually do that in stateless widget's build method and it works like nothing happened