# How to removing black border on navigator in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm currently developing with Flutter, using VS Code as my compiler and Pixel 6 as my simulator, with Android SDK 34. I've encountered an issue where my application's navigator (bottom gesture bar) shows a black border. Here's the code I'm using, derived from the official Flutter docs under the 'navigation bar' section:

```
flutter create --sample=material.NavigationBar.1 mysample
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [NavigationBar].

void main() => runApp(const NavigationBarApp());

class NavigationBarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationBarApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: NavigationExample());
  }
}

class NavigationExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<NavigationExample> createState() => _NavigationExampleState();
}

class _NavigationExampleState extends State<NavigationExample> {
  int currentPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
        destinations: const <Widget>[
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
            label: 'Explore',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.commute),
            label: 'Commute',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
            icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
            label: 'Saved',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text('Page 1'),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text('Page 2'),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text('Page 3'),
        ),
      ][currentPageIndex],
    );
  }
}
```

**Expected Result:**
I am trying to achieve this look on my navigation bar, there is no extra black board under the navigation bar:
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EPLd.png)

**Actual Result:**
But the app is currently showing a black border on the navigation bar like so:
[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpQ8Q.png)

**I've tried:**

1. Other example code from the official Flutter docs.
2. Other simulator like Pixel 5 and resizable simulator.
3. Other SDK like Android 13 or Android 12.

**but the issue still persists.**

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update your `setSystemUIOverlayStyle`, take a look at the [Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html.)

You can see the example there.

Also more info here:

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819118/flutter-where-should-i-call-systemchrome-setsystemuioverlaystylesystemuioverla)
[Source 2](https://medium.com/@mustafatahirhussein/these-quick-tips-will-surely-help-you-to-build-a-better-flutter-app-6db93c1095b6)

Comment: Thanks, I can set the color to red or blue or anything with `setSystemUIOverlayStyle` ,but  how can I make the color exactly same as the default color of navigation bar and change along side when the navigation bar color changes ( for example, I use dynamic color and the navigation bar color is changed according to the theme)

Comment: If you want to change the navigation bar based on the screen, you will have to do it through the AnnotatedRegion 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51013116/9611399

Answer (score 0):

Use systemChrome Function for that

just put this code in either in initState()

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white
      ),
);
```

Comment: you can call it in main() method. It will still work.

Comment: I've tried this and now the black bar become white bar, still slightly different form the navigation bar color: [like this](https://i.imgur.com/Loo1WmC.png)

Comment: Also I use `systemNavigationBarColor:Colors.transparent` still the same.

Comment: make color white. or you can work arround other property as well.

Comment: Thanks, I can set the color to white or red or blue or anything with setSystemUIOverlayStyle ,but is there a way to make the color exactly same as the color of navigation bar and change along side when the navigation bar color changes? ( for example, I use dynamic color and the navigation bar color is changed according to the theme)

Comment: as per my knowledge, you have to set color manually in all screens either pre-define or from API.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an code that sets a transparent navigation bar and system UI overlay:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Set the system UI overlay to transparent navigation bar.
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Hello, World!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To achieve a transparent navigation bar, you can try using the `SystemUiOverlayStyle.light` for the status bar icons and text color. Additionally, you can set the navigation bar color to `Colors.transparent` and set its brightness to `Brightness.dark`.

Comment: I've tried this and now the black bar become white bar, still slightly different form the navigation bar color: [like this](https://i.imgur.com/lucP4NS.png)

Comment: I have updated the code , kindly try this